# Cloudfront does not reliably store images over a period of days

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a webserver which is dynamically generating images for an e-commerce site, and I have set up Amazon Cloudfront in front of this server to cache image requests to reduce load on my own server.

I find that on any given day, images (once loaded a single time that day) are served from cloudfront. e.g:

[image]

The problem is that the image *is* being regenerated (Cloudfront is missing my image and needs to request it from my server) each day, cloudfront seems to ignore the 'max_age' I am defining on my own server and choosing a default of 24 hours. This is the response from the server 'behind' cloudfront:

[image]

Are there any reasons why cloudfront would be ignoring  my 'max-age' value based on the responses I'm sending? To add extra infuriation, it does hold on to some images for more than 24 hours, but never more than a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an artifact of how [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) operates regarding object expiration, see [Specifying How Long Objects Stay in a CloudFront Edge Cache (Expiration)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html):

> Typically, CloudFront serves an object from an edge location until the
>   object expires. After it expires, the next time the edge location gets
>   an end-user request for the object, CloudFront forwards the request to
>   the origin server to verify that the cache contains the latest version
>   of the object:
>
> - If CloudFront already has the latest version, the origin returns only a 304 status code (not modified).
> - If CloudFront does not have the latest version, the origin returns a 200 status code (OK) and the latest version of the object.
>
> **If an object in an edge location isn't frequently requested,
>   CloudFront might evict the object—remove the object before its
>   expiration date**—to make room for objects that are more popular. *[emphasis mine]*

Infrequent object access would also explain why *it does hold on to some images for more than 24 hours, but never more than a couple of days*. This should be evident by the lack of entries in the CloudFront [Access Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html), so in case you aren't positive that those files are frequently requested, checking the logs could yield a definite answer.